# A2lixTranslationFormBundle with Stof DoctrineExtensionsBundle doesnt Show Any Tab

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, stofdoctrineextensions

I'm new to Symfony and Sonata. After following the instructions i installed Translatable, but i dont get any Tab in the form.

[image]

Composer.json

```
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.1.x-dev",
    "a2lix/translation-form-bundle": "2.x-dev"
```

config.yml

```
    # Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        # path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true

        mappings:
            gedmo_translatable:
                type: annotation
                prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Entity
                dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Entity"
                alias: GedmoTranslatable # this one is optional and will default to the name set for the mapping
                is_bundle: false


    stof_doctrine_extensions:
        default_locale: "%locale%"
        orm:
          default:
              translatable: true

a2lix_translation_form:
    locales: [es, pr]       # [1]
    default_required: true      # [2]
    manager_registry: doctrine      # [3]
    templating: "A2lixTranslationFormBundle::default.html.twig"      # [4]
```

Sonata AdminClass

```
/**
 * @param FormMapper $formMapper
 */
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('descripcion')
        ->add('unidadMedida')
        ->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations')
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had so much trouble trying to use those 2 bundles that I switched to using only **a2lix** bundles and it worked like a charm for me...
This is what I am using now (sf 2.4)

```
    "a2lix/i18n-doctrine-bundle": "dev-master",
    "a2lix/translation-form-bundle": "2.*@dev",
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem - cant get Tabs. I have dev-master at i18n-doctrine-bundle and 1.*@dev at translation-form-bundle but stil doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you use "a2lix/i18n-doctrine-bundle": "dev-master", the best is to use the latest "a2lix/translation-form-bundle": "2.*@dev".
About tabs, you should check if you have well load assets  a2lix_translation_bootstrap.js and the dedicated one for tabs from bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)

Comment: In case we would make use of `a2lix/i18n-doctrine-bundle`, what to do with the current database values? And, in case I want just one table with all translations, then the Gedmo strategy is the only option?