# Edit multiple languages column at the same time

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin, doctrine-extensions, a2lix-translation

I am using translatable table by [doctorine2 extension](http://blog.lazycloud.net/en/symfony2-doctrineextentions-translatable/)

I have successfully implemented input and output data for each languages.

However I would like to edit the multiple language at the same time.
like this below
this codes is not correct, however that's what I want to do.

Is there good solution for this purpose?

in  php

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($attrSchool)
        ->add('description fr')
        ->add('description ch)
        ->add('description en)->getForm();
```

in twig

```
<form action="http://myserver.com/">
{{ form_widget(form.description fr) }}
{{ form_widget(form.description ch) }}
{{ form_widget(form.description en) }}

<input type=submit>
</form>
```

---

Now I understood I should use github.com/a2lix/TranslationFormBundle thanks to the @ghanbari 's comment

So, I decided to choose.

"stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.2.*@dev",

and

"a2lix/translation-form-bundle": "1.*@dev",

then set up according to [here](http://a2lix.fr/bundles/translation-form/1.3.html)

then I set up a2lix in my sonataadminbundle class myEntity.php

```
   $formMapper
        ->with('General')
          ->add('description','a2lix_translations_gedmo', array(
'translatable_class' => 'Acme\UserBundle\Entity\myEntity'))
```

when I choose 'Add new' in admin bundle page translation tab appear correctly.

However I choose edit existed-one,

```
Expected argument of type "object, array or empty", "string" given
```

this error message appears.

'Acme\UserBundle\Entity\myEntity' is surely the class existing in my project.

Why it happens ?

Comment: you can use this bundle: https://github.com/a2lix/TranslationFormBundle

Comment: Thanks great suggestion, but I found a2lix is not compatible with my stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle. Same problem is discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990813/a2lixtranslationformbundle-with-stof-doctrineextensionsbundle-doesnt-show-any-ta.

Comment: I will try "a2lix/i18n-doctrine-bundle" at the same time. thanks a lot.

Comment: It seems quite useful, but somehow i18-doctrine-bundle doesn't work well in my environment. I will search another way...

Comment: what is your problem with  i18-doctrine-bundle?

Comment: why u no use https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions ?

Comment: mmm, I didnt' understand the difference between Atralntic18/DoctrineExtensions and stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle. At first I thought stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle include Atrantic18/DoctrineExtension......

Comment: yes, stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle is a bundle for symfony that wrap Atralntic18/DoctrineExtensions

Comment: I understood , so you mean these are basically the same. Now I updated the article....

Comment: you use which sonata version?

Comment: "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/block-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle" : "2.2.7",
        "sonata-project/core-bundle": "~2.2@dev",

These are my setting for sonata